# Nullable<T> implementation

Tags: c#, .net, nullable

I am trying to implement Nullable type. But below mentioned code doesn't support null value for valuetype datatypes.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Nullable
{

    [Serializable, StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]    
    public struct Nullable<T> where T : struct
    {
        private bool hasValue;

        public bool HasValue
        {
            get { return hasValue; }
        }

        internal T value;

        public Nullable(T value)
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.hasValue = true;
        }

        public T Value
        {
            get
            {
                if (!this.hasValue)
                {
                    new InvalidOperationException("No value assigned");
                }
                return this.value;
            }
        }

        public T GetValueOrDefault()
        {
            return this.value;
        }

        public T GetValueOrDefault(T defaultValue)
        {
            if (!this.HasValue)
            {
                return defaultValue;
            }
            return this.value;

        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            if (!this.HasValue)
            {
                return obj == null;
            }
            if (obj == null)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return this.value.Equals(obj);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            if (!this.hasValue)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            return this.value.GetHashCode();
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (!this.hasValue)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }
            return this.value.ToString();
        }

        public static implicit operator Nullable<T>(T value)
        {
            return new Nullable<T>(value);
        }

        public static explicit operator T(Nullable<T> value)
        {
            return value.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

When I trying to assign the value as null, it's throwing an error "Cannot convert null to 'Nullable.Nullable' because it is a non-nullable value type"

What I have to do to resolve this issue?

Comment: why do you want to re-invent the wheel ?

Comment: It's impossible to create a `Nullable` type with the same functionality as the .NET type for several reasons.  This is just one of them.

Comment: just am trying to learn, how they are implemented in the framework

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compiler and runtime have some 'special case' implementation to handle this specifically for the system provided Nullable types, and you can not re-implement them yourself.

Comment: here is something you can take notes from [nullable.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assigning `null` to `Nullable<T>` is just a syntactic sugar for assigning `new Nullable<T>()`, it's part of C# language, and you can't add that feature to you custom type.

C# spec,

> **4.1.10 Nullable types**
>
> A nullable type can represent all values of its underlying type plus
>   an additional null value. A nullable type is written T?, where T is
>   the underlying type. This syntax is shorthand for System.Nullable,
>   and the two forms can be used interchangeably.

> **6.1.5 Null literal conversions**
>
> An implicit conversion exists from the null literal to any nullable
>   type. This conversion produces the null value (§4.1.10) of the given
>   nullable type.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.
[`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a special case. It has special processing on CLR level (this isn't a pure C# language feature - in particular, CLR supports special scenarios for boxing/unboxing nullables).

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring your homegrown Nullable as a `struct`, and a `struct` is not nullable.
You should declare it as a `class` instead.

this code should throw the same error you are having,
switching the Point type declaration from `struct` to `class` should fix it.

```
void Main()
{
    Point p = null;
}

// Define other methods and classes here
struct Point
{
 public int X   {get; set;}
 public int Y   {get; set;}
}
```