# Do nullable value types have special null checking logic?

Tags: c#, nullable

`Nullable<T>` is a ValueType  so you are guaranteed to never have a null reference on a `Nullable<T>`, but the following passes;

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldTestNullRef()
    {
        int? value = null;
        IsNull(value).Should().BeTrue(); // Passes
        IsNull(new Nullable<int>()).Should().BeTrue(); // passes
    }

    private bool IsNull<T>(T nullable)
    {
        return nullable == null;
    }
```

Shouldn't `IsNull` always return false for `Nullable<T>`?

Is this fancy compiler magic?

References to Nullable: (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Edit: 
This is different than
`Which is preferred: Nullable<>.HasValue or Nullable<> != null?`

When I run IsNull for ReferenceTypes It returns *as expected*, but when I decompile I don't see two versions of the method. My question is about the implementation potentially of how perhaps Generics are working with differences to (nullable) structs.  For instance `IsNull` doesn't know that nullable is a struct or a value type.

Comment: "Nullable<T> is a ValueType so you are guaranteed to never have a null reference" uh? it is Nullable which means it CAN be null isn't it

Comment: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/nullable.cs,83

Comment: @Steve No, the OP is correct.  `Nullable` is a value type, so it will never *be* a null reference.  A null reference is, however, implicitly convertible to any nullable type, so you can compare it to null and have it return `true` without it actually being `null`.

Comment: `Nullable<T>.Equals(object)` is overridden. `bool? b = null; if (b == null) { /* put a breakpoint here */ }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629207/nullablet-implementation or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503811/how-are-nullable-types-implemented-under-the-hood-in-net

Comment: @EdPlunkett Can you make that an answer?

Comment: @leat No, because the question is closed, and also I just read that the compiler replaces the comparison to a call to `HasValue`. I'd have to research that before I stuck my neck out.

Comment: If you decompile `IsNull` method, then you should see, that null comparison implemented as `box(nullable) == null`. Now you need to read about special rules for boxing `Nullable<>` type.

Comment: @leat See? I came up with something that seemed plausible but I was full of crap. Let this be a lesson to you.

Comment: @Servy I changed / updated the question can you un-mark as duplicate?