# How is it that can I execute method on int? set to null without NullReferenceException?

Tags: c#, nullable

I have read on MSDN that:

> The null keyword is a literal that represents a null reference, one
>   that does not refer to any object.

But I've seen the following code running without throwing any exception:

```
int? i = null;
var s = i.ToString();
```

So if the variable `i` is null, why can I execute it's method?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx

Comment: Think about it, you have to be able to call `i.HasValue` to determine if it's null or not....how would you be able to do that if there weren't always an instance present.

Comment: In that particular case you can always check the .net source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/nullable.cs.html#d83d2db767b43db7
    `public override string ToString() {
            return hasValue ? value.ToString() : "";
        }`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Because `int?` is actually a `Nullable<Int32>` and [`Nullable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0(v=vs.110).aspx) is a `struct`, and a structure [cannot be null](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx#Main%20Features%20of%20Value%20Types).

It is just how [Nullable types work.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2cf62fcy.aspx) They are not reference values, so they can't be null, but they can have a state when they are considered equivalent to null.

You can get more details about `Nullable<T>` implementation in [how are nullable types implemented under the hood in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2503811/how-are-nullable-types-implemented-under-the-hood-in-net) and [Nullable<T> implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25629207/nullablet-implementation)

---

Though as pointed by @JeppeStigNielsen there is one case  when you can get a NRE:

> However: When boxed to a reference type, special treatment of
>   Nullable<> ensures we do get a true null reference. So for example
>   i.GetType() with i as in the question will blow up with the
>   NullReferenceException. That is because this method is defined on
>   object and not overridable

Comment: And if you look at the [Nullable(T).ToString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9hd15ket(v=vs.110).aspx) docs it mentions that you get an empty string when `HasValue` is false.

Comment: but then why in the debugger variable i shows as null?

Comment: @BudaGavril Because debugger knows about `Nullable<T>` type and slightly cheats to make it look null when it has no value.

Comment: I see, so the debugger misleads here... I wonder if this is indeed a cheat or a bug...

Comment: @BudaGavril It is not a bug, because that's what one usually expects to see after setting variable to null. Though, perhaps, it would have been less misleading to somehow indicate that such `null` is not a `null` in the true sense of that word.

Comment: However: When boxed to a reference type, special treatment of `Nullable<>` ensures we do get a true null reference. So for example `i.GetType()` with `i` as in the question ___will___ blow up with the `NullReferenceException`. That is because this method is defined on `object` and not overridable.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Thanks, didn't think about that case - added to the answer with attribution.

Answer (score 7):

The code you pasted

```
int? i = null;
```

is actually just a shorthand for

```
int? i = new int?();
```

Which is a shorthand for

```
Nullable<int> i = new Nullable<int>();
```

Assigning null is using the implicit operator which you can read more from here [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131346(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: where did you found this? can you give me a link?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx "The syntax T? is shorthand for Nullable<T>, where T is a value type. The two forms are interchangeable."

Comment: Assigning null is not using that implicit operator. Assigning like `int? i = 42;` can be thought of as using that implicit operator. However, C# will have its own built-in implicit conversion from `int` to `int?` so I do not think the C# compiler will actually "issue" a call to the IL method you link. And in case of assigning null, it is sure that the C# built-in implicit conversion from the literal `null` to the type `int?` must be considered to understand why it works.